# How to serialize only derived class in spring boot response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Summary: I would like to show only the `ApplicationException` fields in a response, and ignore the `RuntimeException` properties.

I am implementing a custom exception structure in my application. The base exception is `ApplicationException extends RuntimeException` and the derived exceptions are `ResourceNotFoundException`, and `InvalidRequestException` extends `ApplicationException`. The problem is that when I try to throw `ResourceNotFoundException` or `InvalidRequestException`, spring serializes `RuntimeException` fields which I would like to avoid.

The response that I would like to see

```
{
    "resultCode": -1,
    "message": "xyz@gmail.com kullanıcısı bulunamadı",
    "httpStatusCode": 404,
    "throwedAt": "2023-04-12T15:53:34.532371+03:00"
}
```

The response that is thrown

```
{
    "cause": null,
    "stackTrace": [
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "lambda$loadUserByUsername$0",
            "fileName": "UserDetailsServiceImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": 24,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": "java.base",
            "moduleVersion": "11.0.13",
            "methodName": "orElseThrow",
            "fileName": "Optional.java",
            "lineNumber": 408,
            "className": "java.util.Optional",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "loadUserByUsername",
            "fileName": "UserDetailsServiceImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": 23,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "loginUser",
            "fileName": "AuthService.java",
            "lineNumber": 87,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.service.AuthService",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "<generated>",
            "lineNumber": -1,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.service.AuthService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2f837c1d",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "MethodProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 218,
            "className": "org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invokeMethod",
            "fileName": "CglibAopProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 386,
            "className": "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "access$000",
            "fileName": "CglibAopProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 85,
            "className": "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "intercept",
            "fileName": "CglibAopProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 704,
            "className": "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "loginUser",
            "fileName": "<generated>",
            "lineNumber": -1,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.service.AuthService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$be4b4c81",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "login",
            "fileName": "AuthenticationController.java",
            "lineNumber": 34,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.controller.AuthenticationController",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": "java.base",
            "moduleVersion": "11.0.13",
            "methodName": "invoke0",
            "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": -2,
            "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
            "nativeMethod": true
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": "java.base",
            "moduleVersion": "11.0.13",
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": 62,
            "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": "java.base",
            "moduleVersion": "11.0.13",
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": 43,
            "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": "java.base",
            "moduleVersion": "11.0.13",
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "Method.java",
            "lineNumber": 566,
            "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doInvoke",
            "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
            "lineNumber": 205,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invokeForRequest",
            "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
            "lineNumber": 150,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invokeAndHandle",
            "fileName": "ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java",
            "lineNumber": 117,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invokeHandlerMethod",
            "fileName": "RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java",
            "lineNumber": 895,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "handleInternal",
            "fileName": "RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java",
            "lineNumber": 808,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "handle",
            "fileName": "AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java",
            "lineNumber": 87,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doDispatch",
            "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 1071,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doService",
            "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 964,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "processRequest",
            "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 1006,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doPost",
            "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 909,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 696,
            "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 883,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 779,
            "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 227,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 162,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "WsFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 53,
            "className": "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 189,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 162,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 111,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 189,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 162,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 111,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 189,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 162,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 337,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "FilterSecurityInterceptor.java",
            "lineNumber": 115,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterSecurityInterceptor.java",
            "lineNumber": 81,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 122,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 116,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "SessionManagementFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 126,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "SessionManagementFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 81,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 109,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 149,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "RequestCacheAwareFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 63,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": null,
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
            "fileName": "JwtAuthenticationFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 40,
            "className": "com.napsam.wo.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 117,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "classLoaderName": "app",
            "moduleName": null,
            "moduleVersion": null,
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
            "lineNumber": 346,
            "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        }
    ],
    "resultCode": -1,
    "message": "xyz@gmail.com kullanıcısı bulunamadı",
    "httpStatusCode": 404,
    "throwedAt": "2023-04-12T15:53:34.532371+03:00",
    "suppressed": [],
    "localizedMessage": "xyz@gmail.com kullanıcısı bulunamadı"
}
```

**ApplicationException**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException{

    private int resultCode;
    private String message;
    private int httpStatusCode;
    private ZonedDateTime throwedAt;

    private static final String ZONE_ID = "Europe/Istanbul";

    public ApplicationException(int resultCode, String message, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatus.value();
        this.throwedAt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZONE_ID));
    }

}
```

**ResourceNotFoundException**

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends ApplicationException {
    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(-1,message,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

**ExceptionHandler**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ApplicationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ApplicationException> handleApplicationException(ApplicationException applicationException) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(applicationException, HttpStatus.valueOf(applicationException.getHttpStatusCode()));
    }
```

Comment: Create a separate dto class with only the fields you want to serialize, create an instance of that dto from the exception, serialize the dto.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found so far is ignoring base class properties via the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

I annotated my base exception class(`ApplicationException`) with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and give all base class properties.

such that;

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "stackTrace", "cause","suppressed", "localizedMessage"})
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException{
```

I am still open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a bean you expect in response:

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    private final ApplicationException delegate;

    public ErrorResponse(ApplicationException delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public int    getResultCode()     { delegate.getResultCode(); }
    public String getMessage()        { ... }
    public String getHttpStatusCode() { ... }
    public String thrownAt()          { ... }
}
```

And then return it:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(
    new ErrorResponse(applicationException),
    HttpStatus.valueOf(applicationException.getHttpStatusCode())
);
```

This way your response would NOT be affected by later code or JDK changes.